# Querying data from a combination of columns using Like (SQL Server 2005/8)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with around 15 columns which can be queried with different combination. The table columns for instance is UserID, LocationID, DepartmentID, CoOrdinate1, CoOrdinate2, CoOrdinate3...CoOrdinate15.

To speed up the retrieval of combination of data we have created a Computed field where we are storing the values of these columns in the format :UserID::LocationID::DepartmentID::CoOrdinate1:...:CoOrdinate15: - a sample value would look like :1:100:20:22:39:94:29:..:9:

While this is fine for retrieving data where the index key matches (*=* operator) we are  exploring the best method to fetch combinations.

For instance if the user queries for UserID = 1 and CoOrdinate = 15 we plan to build a Like condition '%:1::%::%::%::%::%::%::%::%::15:%'.

SQL Server is doing an Index Scan to retrieve the data. From a performance point of view - is there a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: Is UserId field the primary key?

Comment: No. There is an id field which is the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me sum this up:

- when query a table, in your where clause you can have an **arbitrary combination of the columns**
- you could create an individual index on each column, but only one of them would be used for your query, as normal b-tree indexes cannot be combined
- you could create [**composite indexes**](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/10/20/composite-indexes/) on certain combination of columns but these indexes would only be used by those queries that have a where clause that matches the columns in the composite index; also, having many wide composite indexes would incur big maintenance overhead
- Since you want to filter against arbitrary combination of the columns in your queries, composite indexes are not an option: you cannot create a composite index for all possible combination of columns

In general, the solution to this problem is having [**bitmap indexes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) on each columns, because bitmap indexes can be combined. Unfortunately SQL Server does not support bitmap indexes but I've heard it has some similar feature. I suggest you look into that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522541.aspx
(This article discuss the usage of bitmap indexes when joining tables, but dont let that confuse you, they can be useful in your use case as well, when you query a single table.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Creation of these indexes are a problem as you highlighted. Out of curiosity - Would a Full text index help in this case?

Comment: Well, not really. At least not with the format you have proposed for the computed field. Imagine you want to search for LocationID=123 and DepartmentID=2 and CoOrdinate1=12. The search result on the full text index would contain records of UserID=123 and DepartmentID=123 and so forth. That is every search would return tons of false positive results.

Comment: Thank you! Will continue to explore possibilities to arrive at a solution for this. Any case the Like usage idea is dropped.

Answer (score 4):

From the information supplied, it looks as though there are up to 15 numerical coordinates for each record on the existing table.

Which means that the existing table is not properly normalised.

I strongly recommend restructuring the existing table to be more like:

```
UserID
LocationID
DepartmentID
CoOrdinate Number
CoOrdinate Value
```

(Alternatively, retain the existing table without the CoOrdinate fields and add a new table with the UserID, LocationID, DepartmentID combination replaced by the key field from the existing table.)

This should allow for much simpler and more efficient querying of data - indexes on numeric fields are much smaller and faster-accessed than on long string fields.

Answer (score 3):

That computed field makes no sense at all. `LIKE` queries are very slow. You can have multiple indexes on a table, including multiple columns as required. You'll be much better off relying on SQL Server's own indexing than trying to roll your own.

Comment: +1 Queries involving `like '%...` generally don't use indexes on the `like` field at all.

Comment: We created the Computed column primarily to create a indexed field with combination of all values in the fields. The other option would be to create a index with all these columns. Further when searching for the all the combination we would then have to add 18 where conditions.

By adding this computed column we are creating 1 index and searching on 1 column.

Comment: But you have 18 WHERE conditions because... you actually have 18 conditions. Concatenating them into one for performance purposes assumes that your string-based implementation is more efficient than the database's internal implementation of the index across multiple columns, surely? I can't think that's right. Regardless, attempting to use your concatenated column with LIKEs is going to be very inefficient. If you're using an RDBMS, why not use its indexing functionality?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I agree that when the problem is considered in isolation then the database internal implementation might seem to be more optimized and the right way to go. But when we consider other problems then the computed columns give us a slight edge which take preference over the performance (and storage) considerations. We will however continue to explore possibilities to arrive at a solution for this. Any case the Like usage idea is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Try simple approach, I'm wrapping it into SP:

```
CREATE PROC Find
@UserId int,
@LocationId int,
....
@CoOrdinate15 int
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT [what you need]
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE 
      (@UserId IS NULL OR UserId = @UserId) 
  AND (@LocationId IS NULL OR LocationId = @LocationId)
  ...
  AND (@CoOrdinate15 IS NULL OR CoOrdinate15  = @CoOrdinate15)
END
```

RECOMPILE causes Sql Server's optimizer to finely adopt each call to SP taking into account NULL-valued parameters and to choose the right index for every call

Answer (score 1):

No. Leading wildcard LIKE searches will always be rubbish.

Do you *really* need complete exhaustive search flexibility?

If you are looking for `'%:1::%::%::%::%::%::%::%::%::15:%'` then you should search correctly with `WHERE x=1 and y=15` and add appropiate indexes.

Comment: The problem is creating the combination of indexes. In fact we created the Computed column primarily to create a indexed field with combination of all values in the fields. This way all locating the combination goes through the index. Further we are expecting this table to be very large.

Comment: @stackoverflow: and? your chosen solution won't seek on the index because of leading wildcards. Also see Mark Bannister's answer about correcting your design

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on the computed field you should construct it such a way:

`"field1=value1;field2=value2;....;fieldn=valuen"`

that is

`"UserID=123;LocationID=34;DepartmentID=2;CoOrdinate1=56;..."`

You would define a [full text index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) on the computed field

For instance if the user queries for UserID = 1 and CoOrdinate = 15 your where clause would be

WHERE CONTAINS(computed_field, "UserID=1" AND "CoOrdinate=15")

You will have to take care of properly indexing "=" and numbers when you define your index. You should treat "=" and numbers as part of the words, so "UserID=1" would be one word in the index.

Comment: In our case anyway the co-ordinates, userid etc. come from a same table so the text can actually be a series of numbers like "180 175 200 199 ..." and the search condition can be WHERE CONTAINS(computed_field, "180" AND "200"). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

build the where clause dinamicaly start with `where 1=1` and append each relevant part as `and xx_field = 'value'` or `and xx_field like '%value%'`

Answer (score 0):

Very good analyse of your case by Erland Sommarskog: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)